# Genode Django App No Longer Serving Properly

Tags: python, django

My Geocode application which is based on Django is no longer serving properly, and I am getting the error detailed as follows:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://52.36.3.179/

Django Version: 1.6.11
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'pagination',
 'taggit',
 'friendlytagloader',
 'geoexplorer',
 'leaflet',
 'django_extensions',
 'autocomplete_light',
 'mptt',
 'modeltranslation',
 'djcelery',
 'pinax_theme_bootstrap_account',
 'pinax_theme_bootstrap',
 'django_forms_bootstrap',
 'account',
 'avatar',
 'dialogos',
 'agon_ratings',
 'announcements',
 'actstream',
 'user_messages',
 'tastypie',
 'polymorphic',
 'guardian',
 'geonode.people',
 'geonode.base',
 'geonode.layers',
 'geonode.maps',
 'geonode.proxy',
 'geonode.security',
 'geonode.social',
 'geonode.catalogue',
 'geonode.documents',
 'geonode.api',
 'geonode.groups',
 'geonode.services',
 'geonode.geoserver',
 'geonode.upload',
 'geonode.tasks')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  137.                 response = response.render()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  81.         context = self.resolve_context(self.context_data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in resolve_context
  159.         return RequestContext(self._request, context, current_app=self._current_app)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py" in __init__
  169.             self.update(processor(request))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geonode/context_processors.py" in resource_urls
  28.     site = Site.objects.get_current()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py" in get_current
  47.             current_site = self.get(pk=sid)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  151.         return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  310.                 self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist.
```

I can provide more configuration settings if need be. Please don't hesitate to ask. I am trying to not have to reinstall the application. This problem happened after I reloaded the server in order to update the correct URL.

Comment: When are you getting this error?